# syntax error, unexpected '$utilisateur' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables

I try to put my code just below but i have an error message : syntax error, unexpected '$utilisateur' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'

I use Laravel version 8.6.0 and php version 7.3.11.

I know i doing to put a ')' in my action code but I can't found the mistake :/

For Laravel the mistakes is here in line 15 :

```
 <form class="level-item" method="post" action="/{{ $utilisateur->email }}/suivis">
```

Thank you guys !

```
enter`@include('header')

<div class="section"> 

    <h1 class="title is-1 level"> 

        <div class="level-left"> 

            <div class="level-item">
                {{ $utilisateur->email }}
            </div>

    @auth 

    <form class="level-item" method="post" action="/{{ $utilisateur->email }}/suivis"> 
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <button type='submit' class="button">Suivre</button>

    </form>

    @endauth

        </div>
    
    </h1>

    @if(auth()-> check() AND auth()-> user()-> id === $utilisateur->id ?? '')

    <form action="/messages" method="post">

        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="field">
            <label class="label"> Message </label>
            <div class="control"> 
                <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Qu'avez vous à écrire ? "> </textarea>
             </div>
             @if($errors->has('message'))
             <p class="help is-danger"> {{$errors->first('message')}} </p>
             @endif
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button is-link" type="submit">Publier</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    @endif

    @foreach ($messages as $message)

    <hr>
    <p>
        <strong> {{ $message->created_at}} </strong><br>
        {{ $message -> contenu }}

    </p>

    @endforeach

</div>
```

@include('footer')` code here

Comment: It should give a file and line number in the error?

Comment: You have spaces after arrow that are used to invoke a method at the line   '@if(auth()-> check() AND auth()-> user()-> id === $utilisateur->id ?? '')' that should probably not be here

Comment: This is a common error of php typo mistake.

Comment: Sorry guys ! I just put the line on my edit. The mistake is in the line 15

Comment: What the line 15 here?

Comment: this line : ''<form class="level-item" method="post" action="/{{ $utilisateur->email }}/suivis">"

Answer (score 1):

```
enter`@include('header')
```

should be

```
@include('header')
```

The problem is in this line:

```
@if(auth()-> check() AND auth()-> user()-> id === $utilisateur->id ?? '')
```

Should be:

```
@if(auth()->check() AND auth()->user()->id === $utilisateur->id)
```

You are assiging `''` to nothing.